How to avoid form resubmission on page refresh after failed request?
I have a nodejs server with server side rendering of relatively simple html pages with handlebars.
Let's say there are two endpoints:
GET /task/new -> open the page with a form for creating a new task
POST /task -> create a new task and redirect to /task/<new task id>
GET /task/:id -> show task details

Tasks have only title with minimal length of 3 symbols:
<form method="post" action="/task">
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input name="title" value="{{titleFromFailedRequest}}"/>
    {{#if validationErrors.title}}
      <span class="error">{{validationErrors.title}}</span>
    {{/if}}
</form>

In this way, if a user opens the page for the first time, the form will be empty.
After the form is submitted there are two scenarios:

If request succeeds, the server will return a redirect to the page with a new task.
If request fails (for example because of too short title), the server will return the same form, with prefilled invalid title and an error message.

The problem is that if I refresh the page after a failed request, the form will be resubmitted. This is not what I want.
I've found information about POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern and I already use it for successful cases. However, I can't find any best practices for failed requests..

Redirecting back to the form after a failed POST is also a good idea. A common pattern is to embed form values in the URL so the form can be prefilled.

You can use these 3 methods. Hope fix your problem.
1: using onsubmit event to prevent submission if error returned from server.
<form id="form1" method="post" action="webpage.php" onsubmit="return cancelSubmit();">
<input id="data1" type="hidden" value="something"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit normal"/>
</form>
<script>
function cancelSubmit(){
let err=true; // read error code returned from server.
if(err){return false;}
else{return true;}
}
</script>

2: using setTimeout to cancel submit process if server or URL is not responding.
<form id="form1" method="post" action="webpage.php">
<input id="data1" type="hidden" value="something"/>
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm();" value="submit js"/>
</form>
<script>
let formSendTimeout;
function submitForm(){
if(!navigator.onLine){return;} // if you are online.
/* 
Some validation (optional).
*/
let form = document.querySelector('#form1');
form.submit();
clearTimeout(formSendTimeout);
formSendTimeout=setTimeout(function(){
form.reset();
location.reload();
},10000);
}
</script>

3: use XMLHttpRequest to send request to server without submission.
<form id="form1" method="post" action="webpage.php">
<input id="data1" type="hidden" value="something"/>
<input type="button" onclick="XMLHttpMode();" value="XMLHttp"/>
</form>
<script>
function XMLHttpMode() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      alert(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "webpage.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("a=A&b=B");
}
</script>

